# Memory usage of webassemblies in webworkers

Tags: webassembly, web-worker, emscripten

I have a large set of webassembly modules.  When I try to dynamically load them in emscripten, I am finding a huge memory overgead that grows linearly with the number of webworkers I have in use with the wasm loaded.

Is this an artifact of the emscripten system I am using or a fundamental limitation?

Note they are using shared memory within the wasm memory space.  The memory usage appears to be within javascript.

In theory we can share the webassembly.module between webworkers; the wasm js interop docs say this is "efficient".  Then instantiate the module in each webworker.

I do not know if the "effixient" includes no huge memory costs.

How do I share a large set of webassembly (100s of mb) between multiple (dozens) of webworkers efficiently, without blowing up memory requirements?  If it requires patching emscripten or bypassing it that is ok.

Comment: I think you will have a better chance at a solid answer if you can provide an example to test against with details. There are so many unknowns to your question, that I could throw a dart and get a better chance of solving this. Which browser are you testing with?

Comment: @JohnHanley I'll see if I can produce a 10 MB toy WASM binary.  I'll double check it happens on every browser; last time it was tested, it was on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about sharing the WebAssmebly Memory? Instead of defining the Memory inside the module itself you can define it outside of the module an then import it. But beware that you module must be ready to share the memory. Sometimes memory location are hardcoded and that could bring you in trouble when sharing Memory.

When you not import the memory every instance will get their own memory which leads to linear increase per instance.

Comment: The memory the webassembly is using for its own purposes is shared.  The memory of the webassembly code itself (the program code) seems to be what is blowing up.  Like, the equivalent of the loaded executable or DLL, as opposed to the memory the executable or DLL allocates when running.

Comment: Can you give example code of what you doing?